# How to move HTML element above or below another element using an animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know I can move an element to above or below another element with a fairly simple JS function. But I would like to make that action animated. Is there an easy way to do that with vanilla JS or jQuery or CSS?

As it is, the action is instantaneous, which is not very obvious and a little jarring.

Consider the code below (or [demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jakemclelland/d13vm4o2/4/)). Most of this gets generated from MVC and razor. But I don't want to distract from the real issue, so I've stripped all that out, down to what gets rendered at the end of the day as a working example. (Sorry it's a bit ugly without the rest of the css and other things there!)

## Code

```js
function moveUp(rowId) {

  var rowSelector = "#" + rowId;

  var myRow = $(rowSelector).closest(".item-row");
  var prev = myRow.prev(".item-row");

  if (myRow.attr("id") != $(".item-row:first").attr("id")) {
    myRow.remove();
    myRow.insertBefore(prev);
  }
}

function moveDown(rowId) {

  var rowSelector = "#" + rowId;

  var myRow = $(rowSelector).closest(".item-row");
  var next = myRow.next(".item-row");

  if (myRow.attr("id") != $(".item-row:last").attr("id")) {
    myRow.remove();
    myRow.insertAfter(next);
  }
}
```

```css
.item-row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-left: 6px solid #006400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="item-panel">
    <div>
      <p>
        Items
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="item-row" id="one">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div onclick="moveUp('one')" title="move up" class="move-up btn">
            <i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
          </div>
          <div onclick="moveDown('one')" title="move down" class="move-down btn">
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p>
            One! Some data and other things
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-row" id="two">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div onclick="moveUp('two')" title="move up" class="move-up">
            <i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
          </div>
          <div onclick="moveDown('two')" title="move down" class="move-down">
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p>
            Two! more data.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-row" id="three">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div onclick="moveUp('three')" title="move up" class="move-up">
            <i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
          </div>
          <div onclick="moveDown('three')" title="move down" class="move-down">
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p>
            Three! And still some more things.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding animation to the new element? Once it's spawned it should trigger the animation, if done correctly.

Comment: Are you referring to the jQuery animate function?

Comment: I'm not big on JQuery so I don't know, I was referring to javascript in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using a combination of the [slideUp()](https://api.jquery.com/slideup/), and [slideDown()](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) jquery functions. The animation closes the two elements together, then swaps them, then slides them out. Here's my [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakemclelland/kbrdc1qs/27/) with these changes

It's not exactly the effect I was hoping for, it feels a little bit like a cheap parlor trick. But, at least gets the job done. The 200 millisecond animation is quick enough that unless you look closely, you may not immediately notice that technically they swap places before the browser actually has the chance to render the sliding animation.

```js
function moveUp(rowId) {

  var rowSelector = "#" + rowId;

  var myRow = $(rowSelector);
  var prev = myRow.prev(".movable-row");

  if (myRow.attr("id") != $(".movable-row:first").attr("id")) {
    var prevGuts = prev.clone();
    
    prev.slideUp(200);
    myRow.slideUp(200);
    
    prev.remove();
    myRow.after(prevGuts);

    myRow.slideDown(200);
    
  } else {
    myRow.closest(".move-up").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}

function moveDown(rowId) {

  var rowSelector = "#" + rowId;

  var myRow = $(rowSelector);
  var next = myRow.next(".movable-row");

  if (myRow.attr("id") != $(".movable-row:last").attr("id")) {
    var myGuts = myRow.clone();
    
    myRow.slideUp(200);
    next.slideUp(200);
    
    myRow.remove();
    next.after(myGuts);

    next.slideDown(200);
  } else {
    myRow.closest(".move-down").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add some css like this

```css
.item-row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-left: 6px solid #006400;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 300ms 1 ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.loading {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

You can force the html do rerender the element, forcing it to animate.

```js
function onMove($element) {
  $element[0].classList.add("loading");
  setTimeout($element[0].classList.remove("loading"), 100);
}

function moveUp(rowId) {

  var rowSelector = "#" + rowId;
  
  var myRow = $(rowSelector).closest(".item-row");
  onMove(myRow);
  var prev = myRow.prev(".item-row");

  if (myRow.attr("id") != $(".item-row:first").attr("id")) {
    myRow.remove();
    myRow.insertBefore(prev);
  }
}

function moveDown(rowId) {

  var rowSelector = "#" + rowId;
  
  var myRow = $(rowSelector).closest(".item-row");
  onMove(myRow);
  var next = myRow.next(".item-row");

  if (myRow.attr("id") != $(".item-row:last").attr("id")) {
    myRow.remove();
    myRow.insertAfter(next);
  }
}
```

Note: This is from your fiddle.

Comment: Nice, at least it fades in. That's a lot better than I had it. I was hoping to animate the movement itself.

Comment: To animate the movement you would need to position absolute them and offset the height. Then you could animate translateY.